# PHP check if referral url is the homepage

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm trying to figure out how to check if the referral url to one of my inner pages is the homepage. This would be easy if the homepage was always www.mysite.com/index.php but what happens when it's simply www.mysite.com?

I know I could simply do

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$pos = strrpos($url, "/");
$page = substr($url, $pos+1, (strlen($url)-$pos+1));
if (substr_count($url, 'index')) echo 'from index ';
```

but I don't have the index.php in my $url variable.

Comment: Have you checked if it works like that? I would assume it would give you the www.mysite.com/index.php every time.

Comment: @Walkerneo It could easily just be www.mysite.com/ if the web server is configured to serve index.php as the default page.

Comment: Exactly, this is my issue, index.php is not present in my homepage url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) can help you here.

```
// An array of paths that we consider to be the home page
$homePagePaths = array (
  '/index.php',
  '/'
);

$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if (empty($parts['path']) || in_array($parts['path'], $homePagePaths)) echo 'from index';
```

**N.B.** This should not be relied upon for anything important. The `Referer:` header may be missing from the request, and can easily be spoofed. All major browsers should do what you expect them to, but hackers and webcrawlers may not.

Comment: Posted 10 seconds before I finish my answer same as you!

Comment: @Hossein ...and I though *I* was rubbish at typing... :-P

Comment: can be `$parts['path']` unset, if system not uses trailing slash?

Comment: @EgorSazanovich Indeed it could be - although this would be a violation of the HTTP specification on the part of the requesting user agent - but this possibility can easily be caught, see edit above

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/index.php")
   echo "Home";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$url = explode('/',$url['path']);
if ($url[1]=='index.html'||empty($url[1])) echo 'from index ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$homepage = "index.php";
$ref_array = explode("/", $referer);
if(trim($ref_array[1]) == trim($homepage) || trim($ref_array[1]) == "") echo "From URL";
```

You should note that yoursite.com/index.php and yoursite.com/ is the same!

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

> `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/')`